# How to use loopback ACL model?

Tags: acl, loopbackjs

I use ACL rules in `model.json` and this works nice, but I found in model-config.js specific option

```
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
```

I do not understand, Why this model here, because it does not affect anything? Or I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some permissions is dynamic and maybe you want to set (unset) in your application.

Assume in your application you want to create a UI to manage permissions for users. You want to deny user1 from accessing the books (reading).

So you can do it with `ACL` model